# dataframe apply += if index does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

For a dataframe, we know that

```
df.loc['a', 'col1'] = 1
```

If index `'a'` does not exist, it will automatically create a row with index `'a'` and set column `col1` = 1. But it seems not work for

```
df.loc['a', 'col1'] += 1
```

How to solve it without checking if the index exists? i.e. if index `'a'` does not exist, it will automatically create row with index `'a'` and set column `col1` = 0, then add 1 to 'col1'.

I tried for `dictionary`:

```
dict = {}
dict['a'] += 1
```

It seems also not allowed, which is different with the `map` in C++

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()  # Empty dataframe
```

```py
def add_assign(df, idx, col):
    """Define a helper function.
    """
    try:
        df.loc[idx, col] += 1
    except KeyError:
        df.loc[idx, col] = 1
    return df
```

```py
df = df.pipe(add_assign, "a", "col1")

print(df)
# Output with no error raised
   col1
a   1.0
```